# WORDPRESS Permalinks - Remove leading zero in date (year/month/day)

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a project... migrate from squarespace to wordpress... In squarespace the date year/month/day has no leading zero in month and day, wordpress has leading zero in month/day. How to remove the leading zero in wordpress permalinks?

Example in squarespace:
2014/8/1/grilled-shrimp-in-lettuce-cups

While in wordpress
2014/08/01/grilled-shrimp-in-lettuce-cups

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
function remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink($permalink, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') // change to your post
    {           
        if ('' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        {               
            $permalink = str_replace(array('%monthnum%', '%day%'), array(date('n', strtotime($post->post_date)), date('j', strtotime($post->post_date))), $permalink);
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('post_type_link', 'remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink', 10, 2); // for custom post types
add_action('post_link', 'remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink', 10, 2); //for post
```

Don't forget to refresh permalink rules.

Comment: and how about a regular post? the array there are custom post type correct? what to put if regular post? ... anyways it is not working... already refreshed permalinks rules.

Comment: @Raphael for post, it's a different filter. I've updated my answer

Comment: the updated code still NO luck... by the way, let me know if im doing the correct way of refreshing permalink rules.. in the settings permalink, i revert to default and save.. and change again to custom permalink... i already did that with regards to refresh permalink rules...

Answer (score 0):

Try this put this in functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'month_link', 'remove_leading_zeros_in_url' );
add_filter( 'day_link',   'remove_leading_zeros_in_url' );

function remove_leading_zeros_in_url( $url )
{
    // no pretty permalinks
    if ( ! $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->get_month_permastruct() )
    {
        return $url;
    }

    return str_replace( '/0', '/', $url );
}
```

Comment: No luck my friend.

Comment: then we both needs to wait for other answer :(